# How to suspend and unsuspend property in order to work as expected in knockout.js

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, binding

I have a function `setServiceId(serviceId)` which is called by clicking on some button and Im passing id of that service.

Also I have `serviceIdSubscrier = vm.selectedServiceId.supsendableSubscribe(changeServiceId)` that listens on every change of serviceId (for example, if I clicked id = 5151, and then 5152, this event will be triggered and called a function `changeServiceId`)
However, now, I want when I click multiple times same service, to be also triggered, as it would trigger when id's are different (for example, I clicked for service id=5151, and then again id=5151) and I would like to have same behavior as it I clicked different id's

this is my whole functions:

```
function setServiceId(serviceId) {
    vm.selectedServiceId(serviceId);
    jQuery.post(rootUrl + 'spaemployeeadmin/GetFirstSearchFilterDateForParent', {
        locationId: vm.selectedLocationId()
    })
        .done(function (data) {
            var dateObj = { day: data.Day, month: data.Month, year: data.Year };
            vm.refreshData(dateObj, null);
        });
}
```

`serviceIdSubscrier = vm.selectedServiceId.supsendableSubscribe(changeServiceId)`

```
function changeServiceId() {
    var currentService = getService();
    if (vm.combineSchedules()) {
        vm.selectedService(currentService || {});
        refreshAllowedTimes().then(function () {
            setTimeByPreviousSelection();
            checkToPushCriteria();
        });
    } else {
        refreshOnServiceType();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If serviceId were an object you could change it to another object with the same values and a change would register.

```
5 === 5 //True
{id: 5} === {id: 5} //False
```